# Naming; dynamically create a variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, naming

To avoid a javascript heap problem, I use multiple arrays: family1, family2,family3 ..., dogs1, dogs2, dogs3 ... Use example: 'family1 and dogs1', or 'family132 and dogs132' to create a new array 'results'.

How do I pass the "id" correctly

```
let  id = 'value here'
this.family + id
this.dogs + id
```

So far my str itself is pushed int the new array: t-h-i-s-.-f-a-m-i-l-y-1

```
for (let i = +0; i < +20; i++) {

  const id = 1;
  let str = 'this.family'+id;   // ?
  let str = 'this.dogs'+id;   // ?

  console.log(str);

  const result = {
      familyType: str[i],       // behavior: t-h-i-s-.-f-a-m-i-l-y-1
      protocol: this.dogs1[i],  // expected original behavior
  };

  results.push(result);

}

}
```

Comment: Use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors). As in `this['family'+id]`

Comment: This looks like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) to me. Why you think there is a "heap problem"?

Comment: @Khauri - thank you, this is correct.

Comment: @Andreas - it is indeed an XY problem: It has to do with npm and/or typescript and/or webpack, but there has been no general solution yet. My app has only one service.ts with two arrays of length 5000 and I am creating a new array with a length of 20 - this should be no problem. In response, I created multiple short arrays and it is working for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for:

```
let str = this['family'+id];
```

But this is generally a bad design pattern. Don't name your variables with incremental numbers. Use 2D arrays (i.e. arrays having arrays as values), like `this.dog[id][i]`. If you have *"a javascript heap problem"*, then it is caused by some other code.

Comment: thank you, I will try to implement this. The javascript heap problem occurs as 'too long string' in ionic 3. The array length is 5000, if I split the arrays the heap problem goes away.

Comment: You're welcome. NB: Possibly it is worth asking another question dedicated to the "too long string" ionic3 error (providing code with which it can be reproduced). There might be other users of ionic3 that struggle with the same error.

Comment: It seems to have to do with npm and/or typescript and/or webpack, but there has been no general solution been posted. My app has only one service.ts with two arrays of length 5000 and I am creating a new array with a length of 20.

Comment: Thank you, I will use your solution for now and implement the 2D array later. Is this bad design pattern a real issue or rather an academic one for my use case ?

Comment: It is a real issue in the sense that your code will be harder to manage. Arrays give you also a lot of benefits: a dynamic length property, methods to iterate over and map values, sort, and find values. You can then avoid even the use of indexes with hard-coded (20) end-conditions. The code will look a lot more elegant and will be less prone to bugs.